# Show / Hide Fields in Pentaho Report Based on User Input

Tags: pentaho

I'm trying to show / hide fields in a Pentaho report based upon user input.

For example, I would like to offer a checkbox to the user saying "Show Product Count" -- if the box is unchecked, it will not include that column in the report.

Is there a way to do this in Pentaho Report Designer, perhaps using Parameters?

Thanks for the help -Monica

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have half the answer.  Have a Yes/No Parameter "ShowProductCount"

Then on the conditional fields, go to the visible property, click the + formula icon and enter:

=IF([ShowProductCount]="Yes"; TRUE(); FALSE())

Simple! :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Codek. I made a table with TRUE and FALSE as values, and a parameter to offer those choices. However, when I set the visible property to the formula, it doesn't go away. In fact, if I just set the property to visible = "false" with no formula, it still doesn't go away. Is there some setting that I don't have correctly?

Comment: Answering my own question, I needed to set the band to "invisble-consumes-space" = FALSE to make the whitespace disappear.

Answer (score 2):

There is more to this that the above answer. For example, if you don't want a field to show on the report, you pass the value mentioned above by Codek but the field will not show but the space for it will. The field has to be in a BAND and the band layout has to be set to ROW. Also, on the field you want to not display or display based on user selection, you have to set that field's style properties under size & position - invisible-consumes-space = false.