# Pentaho Show / Hide Fields in Pentaho Report Based on User Input

Tags: grails, pentaho

Show / Hide Fields in Pentaho Report Based on User Input.

Version : Pentaho RD version : 5.2.0.0-209

Efforts :
I have used the banding element and the functionality formula to 'invisible consumes space'
I have used two bands one within another, with different layouts 'block' and 'row' to remove both spaces for invisible elements (in rows and columns).

Result :
It is giving appropriate result and working fine in Pentaho Report Desinger tool itself while updating Query to fetch any field either col1,col2 etc...
- It removes the hiding empty column space from row and column both. Agreed with that.

*Problem :
It still shows the blank Invisible Consumes column Space when doing that .prpt report integration in web application. eg. Grails

Please help me to come out from the problem.
Thanks.

Comment: @Joshua Moore  Yes, its a twice thanks for that. But the problem description is different. Can u tell any resolution for the problem ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show / Hide Fields in Pentaho Report Based on User Input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597884/show-hide-fields-in-pentaho-report-based-on-user-input)